# How to make multiple subreports?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I try to get 2 subreports in my main report.
The subreports works separately but don't work together.

My main report:

[image: Main Report]

I want it to look like this, but the lines are broken when it is too much.

Müşteri Hizmet Kayıtları
[image: subreport]

"Müşteri Hizmet Kayıtları" sub-report looks correct, but then comes to the front and end of "Müşteri Ödeme Kayıtları" sub-report.

It works without problems when the row number is small but it gets broken like this when the number of rows is large.

[image]

My codes:

```
DataTable dt = _datab.TableDataTable($"SELECT * FROM CariHizmetbyCari where CariId={_cari.CariId}");
DataTable dt2 = _datab.TableDataTable($"SELECT * FROM CariMuhasebebyCariHizmetId where CariId={_cari.CariId}");

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dt2);

        rptCariTotal rptCariTotal = new rptCariTotal();
        rptCariTotal.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dataSet.Tables[0]);
        rptCariTotal.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(dataSet.Tables[1]);
        rptCariTotal.SetParameterValue("pAdSoyad", _cari.CariAdı);
        rptCariTotal.SetParameterValue("pMail", _cari.Mail);
        rptCariTotal.SetParameterValue("pTelefon", _cari.Telefon);
        rptCariTotal.SetParameterValue("pWebSite", _cari.WebSite);
        crvViewer.ReportSource = rptCariTotal;
        crvViewer.Refresh();
```

Comment: In the 2nd select CariMuhasebebyCariHizmetId should be the table name CariMuhasebebyCari

Answer (score 0):

You can't have that first sub-report in Page Header.

Create two detail sections ( Right Click on Detail - Insert Section below) and set each sub report in each one.